# ABS - Tab Bar Above Top Bar

Tags: android, tabs, actionbarsherlock

**Description & Problem:**

I'm using **ActionBarSherlock** i found that they are a bug in ABS, so my issue that i need to put tab bar at top bar (one line, like shown on the screenshot) already tried this [solution](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ActionBarSherlock/issues/327) but without effect.

[image]

I note that i don't have this problem on tablet. The problem is on 5.4° devcie Note III.

Answer (score 0):

This is the normal behavior. On Large screen (tablet) or on landscape phone screen, Tab bar is included to top bar, and on small screen Tab bar is below top bar.

Try to add a [SlidingTabLayout](https://developer.android.com/samples/SlidingTabsBasic/src/com.example.android.common/view/SlidingTabLayout.html) as a custom ActionBar view